# C# time delay on application

Tags: c#, timer, delay

I am currently developing an application, I would like to implement a time delay. I don't want to use System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(x); as I read this stalls the thread (UI freezes)

The code I have currently written is:

```
public void atimerdelay()
{
    lblStat.Text = "In the timer";
    System.Timers.Timer timedelay;
    timedelay = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
    timedelay.Enabled = true;
    timedelay.Start();
}
```

I know atimerdelay() does get called (using lblStat), but their is no delay of 5 seconds. I have read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx but I can't work out why the above code is not working.

Additional information - (added for Hamlet Hakobyan)

The application is a 'card checker' application (University project - no real information is used or stored). Once the user has filled out all the relevant and click 'check' a list of validation methods are called. Before any of these are called a ping is carried out to make sure a live internet connection is on the computer. I want to add a slight delay between the ping and the starting of the validation.

Comment: If you really need to wait in UI thread nothing can help you. You still frozen.

Comment: If you can explain your real situation I suppose there is another way to solve your issue.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Added some information about what the application is and what I want it to do

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
await Task.Delay(5000)
```

? It won't block UI thread and looks pretty good!

Comment: That looks awesome. What does it do behind the scenes?

Comment: The await-Keywork was introduced by the .net-framework 4.5. 
Take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/357724/Async-Await-Could-Be-Better

Comment: You should know what is async\await and how they work to understand this statement, see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I'll never forget [this wonderful snippet](http://www.vcskicks.com/loop-time.php). Its suitable for Windows Form Applications, and much more lightweight than creating a `Timer`.

Comment: Does work. Not the most elegant coding I have seen but nice to know I have something, cheers

Answer (score 1):

After search for a delay function (not using *Sleep*) I found this

```
public static DateTime PauseForMilliSeconds(int MilliSecondsToPauseFor)
{
    System.DateTime ThisMoment = System.DateTime.Now;
    System.TimeSpan duration = new System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, MilliSecondsToPauseFor);
    System.DateTime AfterWards = ThisMoment.Add(duration);

    while (AfterWards >= ThisMoment)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
        ThisMoment = System.DateTime.Now;
    }

    return System.DateTime.Now;
}
```

It works perfectly, tested with `.NET 4.0`. Maybe this can be useful for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `System.Timers.Timer` to fire an event after a time interval has passed. They are not useful for simply delaying execution.

If you had added: `timedelay.Elapsed += delayedFunction;` to your code, then  `delayedFunction` would have been called after 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

> Once the user has filled out all the relevant and click 'check' a list
>   of validation methods are called. Before any of these are called a
>   ping is carried out to make sure a live internet connection is on the
>   computer. I want to add a slight delay between the ping and the
>   starting of the validation.

It is good practice, that all your long-playing tasks do in separate thread. If you have `.NET 4.0+` you can use `Task` ([TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx)). If your tasks interact with `UI` you can use [Event-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wewwczdw.aspx) if no `TPL` available.

Specific about `Ping` you can use `Ping.SendAsync`. Please examine the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13458210/ping-over-a-period-of-time/13458382#13458382) for more detail.

Try these and return with new, more interesting questions.